# How do I change type Future<dynamic> to type bool for Shared Preferences

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to be able to use shared preferences to grab some boolean value that I save, so I can use that value to set a switch when I first open up that page. The error I am getting is this

**type 'Future' is not a subtype of type 'bool'.**

I believe what I am getting at the moment is a type Future. What do I need to do to the Future to just get the bool part?

```
 class Settings extends StatefulWidget {
  createState() => SettingsState();
}

class SettingsState extends State<Settings> {

  getPrefValue(String prefsKey) async {
    SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((onValue) {
      if(onValue.getBool(prefsKey) == null){
        return true;
      }
      return onValue.getBool(prefsKey);
    });
  }



  var skinOnSwitch = true;
  var skinlessSwitch = true;

  _saveChickenSelection() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState((){
      prefs.setBool("skinlessPref", skinlessSwitch);
      prefs.setBool("skinPref", skinOnSwitch);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
      body: Container (
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            begin: Alignment.bottomLeft,
            end: Alignment.topRight,
            stops: [0.3,0.7],
            colors: [Colors.pink[300], Colors.pink[900]]
          )
        ),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Text("SETTINGS",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 40)),
                )
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Text("SKINELESS BONELESS Calculation"),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Switch(
                    value: getPrefValue("skinlessPref"),
                    onChanged: (value){
                      setState(() {
                        skinlessSwitch = value;
                        _saveChickenSelection();
                      });
                    },
                    activeTrackColor: Colors.redAccent,
                    activeColor: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Text("SKIN ON< BONE ON Calculation"),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Switch(
                    value: getPrefValue("skinPref"),
                    onChanged: (value){
                      setState(() {
                        skinOnSwitch = value;
                        _saveChickenSelection();

                      });
                    },
                    activeTrackColor: Colors.redAccent,
                    activeColor: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
                  ),
                )
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Any explanation/help would be most appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Can you please share getInstance() method code? It is difficult to understand without it.

Comment: your question is not clear. Please highlight the issue you are facing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a FutureBuilder.

Instead of

```
Switch(
    value: getPrefValue("skinlessPref"),
    ...
```

use

```
FutureBuilder<bool>(
    future: getPrefValue("skinlessPref"),
    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<bool> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData){
            return Switch(
                value: snapshot.data,
                ...
        }else{
            return Container();
        }

    }
)
```

You should also change your getPrefValue to:

```
Future<bool> getPrefValue(String prefsKey) async {
    var prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    if (prefs.getBool(prefsKey) == null){
        return true;
    }
    return prefs.getBool(prefsKey);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to rewrite your `getPrefValue` function to the following:

```
Future<bool> getPrefValue(String key) async {
  final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();  
  return prefs.getBool(key) ?? false;
}
```

This is more clear on what is happening, the null-aware operator `??` already checks null values.

Then, you can use a [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) on your widget tree as the other answer says.

Comment: Thank you for the input!